# Convergence of Variance

Tags: probability-theory

If $X_n \rightarrow c$ as surely where $c$ is a constant and $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables. Is it true that $Var(X_n) \rightarrow 0$? Assume $X_n$ are independent or pairwise independent, and square integrable.

Comment: And assuming the $X_n$'s are square integrable? Not everything has a variance (or even an expectation).

Comment: Yes, that too. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X_n$ has the following distribution:
$$
X_n = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{ w.p. } 1- \frac{1}{n^2}\\
n^3&\text{ w.p. } \frac{1}{n^2}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Then $X_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{a.s.} 0$, but $$\mathbb{E}[X] = n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$$ and $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = n^4 \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty\,.$$